# Копия поля объекта C#

Tags: c#

Есть объект вида:

```
class Foo()
{
    Dictionary<string, int> _a;

    ....

    public Dictionary<string, int> getA()
    {
        return _a;
    }
}
```

Я присваиваю значение поля в другом классе чтобы работать с этими значениями (пример):

```
Dictionary<string, int> temp = Foo.getA();
```

Но если я удаляю запись из словаря, то она удаляется не из текущей переменной, а из поля объекта `Foo`.

> Вопрос: как сделать копию значения поля **_a** из класса **Foo**?

P.S. Поскольку вопрос оказался слишком широк для интерпретаций возможных вариантов, поясню следующее. В переменной `_a` хранится список файлов приложения с их размером. Когда происходит обновление приложения, я просто сравниваю текущее состояние директории с референсным списком файлов в цикле `foreach()`. Те файлы, которые не требуют обновлений я удаляю из переменной которой присвоил значение `Foo.getA()`, а оставшиеся передаю в поток чтобы произвести необходимые манипуляции. Так вот после повторного вызова проверки целостности приложения список пуст, т.к. при повторном вызове значения из поля `_a` их уже меньше и они все подчищаются т.к. все файлы совпадают.

Comment: Сделать копию всего `Dictionary`? =/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
public Dictionary<string, int> getA()
{
    return _a.ToDictionary(x=>x.Key, x=>x.Value);
}
```

Ну или

```
public Dictionary<string, int> getA()
{
    return new Dictionary<string, int>(_a);
}
```

Comment: Это в общем случае shallow copy, и получатель может изменить _сами объекты_ (если там вместо `int` будет целый объект). Хотя хорошего общего решения я как-то и не вижу.

Comment: @VladD так речь не идет о deep copy, только shadow как я понял.

Comment: @tym32167: У ТС иммутабельные ключи и значения, ему всё равно. Но в общем случае...

Comment: @VladD в общем случае надо писать метод с указанием типа копирования и либо сериализовать\десериализвать, либо элементы в словарике должны поддерживать нужное копирование. Но это уже дебри, зачем они в таким простом вопросе?

Comment: @tym31267: Интересно же!

Comment: @VladD ну, для ключей юзать изменяемые объекты было бы странно. Для значений - как я уже сказал, надо будет метод писать с параметром (или 2 метода) для указания типа копирования. Не думаю, что есть какое то генерик решение для подобной задачи, ибо как всегда при глубоком копировании встанет вопрос циклических ссылок, степени глубины копирования, сохранения ссылок на объекты, что не надо копировать и тд. Лично я если могу от такой радости  отбрыкаться другим решением, то 146% попытаюсь это сделать :)

Comment: @tym32167 использовать объекты как ключи - довольно частая практика. Их состояние может меняться. Но hashcode нет.

Comment: @tym32167: `ICloneable`?

Comment: @VladD `ICloneable` - это только 1 метод без параметров, ещё и object возвращает - отличный пример плохого дизайна. Если уж и реализовывать что то, то изобретать IClonable<T>, но это от задачи зависит. Ради 1 случая я бы не стал интерфейс добавлять

Comment: @tym32167: Ну, этот интерфейс по крайней мере уже существует :)

Comment: @Suvitruf `Их состояние может меняться. Но hashcode нет.` - у меня такого в практике не было, да и это как то противоречит назначению хеш функции, разве нет?

Comment: @VladD :) Но это не значит, что его надо использовать

Comment: @tym32167 хешфункция обычно на идентификаторе завязана, который не меняется во время жизни объекта. По крайней мере, в моей практике было. Если хешкод меняется, то при добавлении такого объекта в мепу будет сущий ад)

Comment: @Suvitruf поэтому я использую неизменяемые типы как ключи, чтобы не было такого, что вы описываете. А если хеш код считается от идентификатора, то надо наверное как ключ в словаре использовать идентификатор, а не объект целиком

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Завтра вечером проверю. Вопрос дополнил условием использования словаря.

Comment: Первый пример работает исправно. Спасибо.