# Тот же экземпляр или копия?

Tags: c#, объекты, оператор-присваивания

В классе объекта xml:

```
public List<Student> getStudentsList()
{
    return students;
}
```

В исполнении:

```
List<Student> students = xml.getStudentsList();
```

В итоге в переменной students в исполнении у меня будет тот же объект, что и в объекте xml (передастся указатель) или это будет новый объект, равный старому (передастся значение)? И если это будет один и тот же объект, как можно сделать так, чтобы они были разными? Метода Clone у листа нет.
Знаю, что вопрос кажется глупым, но я ещё новичок и не совсем разобрался с этой системой присваивания по указателю и по значению. Заранее Спасибо.

P.S. нашёл возможное решение: в методе прописать следующее:

```
return new List<Student>(students);
```

В другом вопросе ([https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/871704/Копия-поля-объекта-c](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/871704/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B0-c)) так делали с Dictionary. Пользовались таким методом?

Comment: объект будет тот же. да можно вызывать `new List<Student>(students);`

Comment: Можно ещё linq-метод `ToList()` использовать. / Отмечу, что в любом случае в новом списке вы получите ссылки на те же объекты `Student` (если это ссылочный тип).

Comment: Ответы выше верны. Вы можете сами убедиться в этом. Можно создать метод, выводящий на экран все объекты (ну или хотя бы один) списка `students` объекта `xml`. После этого можно с помощью вашей же функции `getStudentsList()` получить список студентов, а затем его изменить, например, удалив какой-то из его членов, а затем вновь вывести на экран исходный список объекта `xml`.